# Aadi Jagadguru Shankaracharya: where is this shloka from ? - parasyeva brahmaṇaḥ praveśa śravaṇā tādātmyo upadeśā ca

Tags: scripture, upanishads, adi-shankaracharya, shloka, commentary

Hi Trying to identify from where this shloka is:

> parasyeva brahmaṇaḥ praveśa śravaṇā tādātmyo upadeśā ca

परस्येव ब्रह्मणः प्रवेश श्रवणा तादात्मयो उपदेशा च

```
अरस्येव (arasyeva): Like the sap, as in the case of
ब्रह्मणः (brahmaṇaḥ): Brahman
प्रवेश (praveśa): Entry
श्रवणा (śravaṇā): Listening
तादात्म्यो (tādātmyo): Identity, oneness
उपदेशा (upadeśā): Instruction, teaching
च (ca): And
```

based on the audio lecture it was mentioned that it is a commentary by **aadi Jagadguru Shankaracharya**

Does anyone know the reference/source for this?